# Showing both sides are equivalent

Tags: measure-theory

Let h be a measurable function relative to $\mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{F}$ and define $h: F \longmapsto E$. Why is it true that
$$\mathbf{1}_B \circ h = h^{-1} B$$

I tried expanding the term $$\mathbf{1}_B \circ h = \begin{cases}
1    &if \text{ h(x) } \in B\\
0    &if \text{ h(x) } \notin B 
\end{cases}$$

and couldn't go any further.

Thank you in advance for any help rendered.

Comment: The equivalence is not correct. On one side you have a number, $0$ or $1$ and on the other side a set of points. Keep in mind: $h^{-1}(B)=\{x\in F:h(x)\in B\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP surely meant 
$$\chi_B\circ h=\chi_{h^{-1}(B)}.$$
It follows from the equivalence 
$$h(x)\in B\mbox{ if and only if } x\in h^{-1}B.$$